# How to run script with boost::process::system?

Tags: c++, boost

My script:

`ps aux | awk '{s += $3} END {print s}'`

So I'm trying to execute it

```
namespace bp = boost::process;

bp::ipstream out;
bp::system("ps aux | awk '{s += $3} END {print s}'", bp::std_out > out);

std::string line;
std::getline(out, line);
```

Output:

```
error: garbage option
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you don't need manually piping. You just need to inform a shell of your command:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b70f6a7f1a71fcb6)**

```
#include <boost/process.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    namespace bp = boost::process;

    bp::ipstream out;
    std::vector<std::string> args {
        "-c", "ps aux | awk '{s += $3} END {print s}'"
    };
    bp::system(bp::search_path("sh"), args, bp::std_out > out);

    for (std::string line; std::getline(out, line);) {
        std::cout << "output line: " << std::quoted(line) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints, e.g.:

```
output line: "90.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a pipe object (p in this case). Then pass the output from the first process to the next one.

```
bp::ipstream out;
bp::pipe p;
bp::system("ps aux", bp::std_out > p);
bp::system("awk '{s += $3} END {print s}'", bp::std_in < p, bp::std_out > out);
```

Referring the boost [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.io).

Comment: Thanks, but now I have a different error: awk: Invalid character ' in expression

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good solution. As the docs explain, it's asking for deadlocks